# gnuplot: 3d surface, with 2d line graph on the y,z axis wall

Tags: gnuplot

I've made a 3d surface plot in gnuplot, and I'm wondering if it's possible to plot an unrelated 2d line graph on the 'wall' of the y,z axis.
So in essence, I take my x,y line plot but paste it on to the y,z axis.

Similar to a contour plot on the x,y, under a 3d surface, but different.

Comment: Are you plotting functions or data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be precisely what you are looking for, but it is a way to plot a function on a 'wall' of your splot box:

```
#!/usr/bin/env gnuplot

set term png 
set output 'test.png'

# this is the function you want on the wall
myfun(x,y) = y**2

# set the ranges manually
xmin = -10 
xmax = 10
ymin = -10 
ymax = 10

x_range = xmax - xmin
y_range = ymax - ymin

scaler = 0.001
x1 = xmin - x_range*scaler
x2 = xmin + x_range*scaler
x3 = xmax - x_range*scaler
x4 = xmax + x_range*scaler
y1 = ymin - y_range*scaler
y2 = ymin + y_range*scaler
y3 = ymax - y_range*scaler
y4 = ymax + y_range*scaler

xminwall(x,y) = (x > x1 && x < x2) ? myfun(x,y) : 1/0 
xmaxwall(x,y) = (x > x3 && x < x4) ? myfun(x,y) : 1/0 
yminwall(x,y) = (y > x1 && y < x2) ? myfun(x,y) : 1/0 
ymaxwall(x,y) = (y > x3 && y < x4) ? myfun(x,y) : 1/0 

splot sin(x), xminwall(x,y)
```

Here is the result:

[image]

What the script does is plots the function you want to plot on the wall (myfun(x,y)) and does a splot of it, restricted to values that are very close to the wall.  The surface mesh has a certain number of gridpoints, and one of those points is always at the x and y limits.

In this example, if I had just done `splot sin(x), y**2`, I would have gotten two overlapping surfaces.

I made four functions (`xminwall`, etc.) so you can plot on the wall at the x/y range minimum/maximum walls.  Note that `mufun(x,y)` has to be a function of the correct x and y in order for the plot to show up properly on the wall, otherwise you might get a straight line.